# Toggle Button State in ViewPager when a page is removed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, togglebutton

I have a toggle button (in all pages) to allow users to like the contents of a page (of viewpager).

When user unlikes a page, the page gets removed from the viewpager.

Below is the cycle

> User "Unlikes" -> Updates SQLite -> NotifyDatasetChanged() -> Fragments
>   Rebuilt -> Viewpager displayed

The issue is suppose I am in position 2 and I "unlike" - The page gets removed - in its place a new page is placed with the same toggle button state as that of the removed page, whereas I expect the togglebutton state to be set based on actual value returned by the Cursor.

Even though "isChecked()" status of the ToggleButton is "true" and is being returned in getItem() as a part of rootview - and is also being displayed in a mock TextView I created - Somehow the "Checked" State is retained from the removed page.

**Adapter**

```
public class CursorPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    .
    .
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

            if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                fragment = new myDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            }
        return fragment;

    }
}
```

**Population**

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ToggleButton addFav = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addFavorite);

            .
            .

             if (item_status.equals("0")) {
                addFav.setChecked(false);
                afw.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
             } else (item_status.equals("1")) {
                addFav.setChecked(true);
                afw.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
             }

            .
            .

            addFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final Context ctx = getActivity();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
                        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.dap.qgit", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) v;
                        if (tb.isChecked()) {
                            values.put(DataProvider.COL_ITEM_STATUS, "1");
                        } else {
                            values.put(DataProvider.COL_ITEM_STATUS, "0");
                        }

                        String[] args = new String[1];
                        args[0] = "" + tb.getTag();
                        ctx.getContentResolver().update(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_ITEM, values, "item_id=?", args);
                        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_TAG_ITEMS,null);

                    }
                });
      }
```

Comment: Share your code. Adapter and population part.

Comment: @azizbekian I have updated

Comment: What is `item_status` and where is it being initialized?

Comment: item_status comes from database/cursor - Part of CursorPagerAdapter - Cascaded to "Population/ItemDetailFragment" through Argument Bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First please read "Martin Albedinsky" reply - Thanks to him for helping me isolate the issue.

I used the below in my layout XML to circumvent the issue:

```
                 <ToggleButton
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        android:saveEnabled="false"
                        .
                        .
                        .
                  >
```

Though I have not personally tried Martin's solution - which by his explanation appears to be a cleaner approach.

I am yet to ascertain if this solution that worked for me causes any performance/untoward issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to consider when using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` implementation with a **dynamic** data set like `Cursor`.

### Issues

1. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` from the support library **maps** its instantiated fragments **to theirs** corresponding **positions** not to theirs corresponding ids,
2. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` by default does not support **dynamically** changing data set as you can see by implementation of `getItemPosition(Object object)` which always returns `POSITION_UNCHANGED`

### Solutions

1. You need to use implementation of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which **maps** its instantiated fragments **to theirs** corresponding **ids** from the `Cursor` and is also capable to **restore state** of those fragments by theirs corresponding ids,
2. Such adapter implementation also needs to **return proper position** of a fragment according to position of its associated data in the `Cursor` via
   `getItemPosition(Object object)` method.

Now, you may implement/port `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` from the support library, so such implementation provides both, mapping by ids and proper position resolving features or you may use some library which already provides such features for you, like [this](https://github.com/universum-studios/android_pager_adapters) library which provides the first feature and the second one may be simply implemented by [this](https://gist.github.com/albedinsky/6d38f2d94b85d6000d264d7e1189cc2e) **GitHub Gist**.

Comment: Hi Martin, With my current implementation, the data of each page changes as expected - only the CheckBox/ToggleButton state is goofed up - Say I have 10 pages and I unlike a page then only 9 pages are displayed - with correct content in each page as expected - only the state of the Checkbox/ToogleButton is incorrect - Even though getItem method is called and in getItem method the value for ToogleButton is correctly set.

Comment: On your comment of  "...is also capable to restore state of those fragments by theirs corresponding ids..." - Does it mean it would restore state of CheckBox/ToggleButton even when I have not written any explicit "SavedInstanceState" routines

Comment: Well there are so many things going on under the hood, as by the `FragmentManager` so by the `ViewPager` in order to "properly" manage displayed fragments. Basically, all statefull widgets like `CheckBoxes` save theirs state whenever appropriate. In this case theirs stored state is associated with theirs corresponding `Fragment`. Now, lets say you **destroy** fragment at position `[2]`, its view's state is saved, a new fragment is created for that position and its view's state is restored for that same position, but that fragment already represents another item, this is the **inconsistency**.

Comment: `PagerAdapter` has `saveState(...)` and `restoreState(...)` methods which are called by the `ViewPager` to which is such adapter attached. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` implements these methods and manages **saving** and **restoring** of state for its instantiated `Fragments`. The best place where you can restore the fragment view's state properly is in `Fragment.onViewStateRestored(...)`method, where you should use data from the fragment's arguments. But still, if you are using `Cursor` as PagerAdapter's data set, you shouldn't rely on default implementation of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks Martin - Your explanation on how Android automatically attempts to preserve the state of Built-In Widgets such as ToggleButton/CheckBox etc., really helped me. I have for now used "android:saveEnabled="false" in my layout xml to circumvent the issue temporarily - This blog did help me - http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/

Comment: I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter for it behaves like a listview creating and destroying view as and when needed - I have a huge bunch of pages and don't want to clog the memory. I however do not require any "State" restore - Would you agree with me that "android:saveEnabled="false"" would be an acceptable solution ?

Comment: @takrishna Yes the solution disabling the state saving feature when you basically saves and restores state of that view is acceptable. However, you are still depending on checked state that is stored in `Bundle` arguments that are associated with a specific fragment and these arguments are also stored/restored by the `FragmentManager` alongside state saving logic of `PagerAdapter` which is based on positions of fragments and not by **ids** of items in the data set. Still it all depends on how you implemented `PagerAdapter.getItemPosition(int)` method for your adapter.